# Using python wrapper for EtherPad lite

Tags: python, api, etherpad

I've been trying to use Etherpad lite/beta API via [PyEtherpadLite](https://github.com/devjones/PyEtherpadLite).

My question is that where do I find my API Key ? As per the documentations, the api key is stored in a .txt file in the base dir of the client folder. But my actual question is that i just want to access [this](https://beta.etherpad.org/api) pad via API which is hosted by someone. So now where will i find the api key?

In another blog, I found that the Api key for  https://beta.etherpad.org/ is EtherpadFTW. 
But that doesn't seems to be working. I'm getting no or wrong API Key response.

Answer (score 2):

Don't use the beta.etherpad.org API, it's not for public consumption.

The API key is in your Etherpad Server home folder as APIKEY.txt

You can't use the API of another instance unless they give you the API Key.

I maintain the beta.etherpad.org site, I don't see the value in exposing the API Key publicly.